# Issue with fgetcsv causing loop in CLI but not apache2

Tags: php, command-line-interface, fgetcsv

I'm a bit stuck with the following code which correctly opens a csv file (list.csv) and detects whether there is a match in one of the lines that matches what is in the variable $match. Just to clarify, the script works correctly. When I call the script via a browser there are no errors shown (I have them enabled), but when I run it in CLI it get's into a loop with the following errors:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/html/script.php on line 169
Exclusion not found<br>
Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/script.php on line 165
```

and just repeats itself...

Line 169 is `if( in_array( $match ,$line ) )`

Line 165 is `while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {`

```
if ($check_list == "1") {
    $file = fopen('list.csv', 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($line);

    if( in_array( $match ,$line ) )
        {
        echo "match found";
        $name = $line[0];
        $address = $line[1];
        $phone = $line[2];
        echo "name : " . $name;
        echo "address : " . $address;
        echo "phone : " . $phone;
        }
    else {
        echo "Not found in file.";
        }

}
fclose($file);
}
```

I'm a bit stuck as to why it is behaving this way via CLI, but not via browser (that I can see).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can be caused by file path or file permission. In the browser does it produce any output?

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to add, file exists and is read correctly, the script (seems) to work fine.

Comment: You mean it kept running even after the csv reached EOF ?

Comment: I'd check to see if the same path definition and permissions will work for both the CLI and through Apache. And I'd like to see that $match is definied. It's pretty clear from your errors that fgetcsv is where the failure is happening.

Comment: Yes, when run in a browser the script continues to run successfully

Comment: When you run via cli you are running the script as a different user than the webserver.

Comment: Yes, browser runs as www-data and I'm running CLI as root

Comment: You do realize that the path to the file is relative to your working directory not relative to the script, right ? Try using absolute path.

Comment: The file is loaded correctly as it searched through it and finds a match

Comment: I've just checked the php.ini in both /etc/php5/apache2 and /etc/php5/cli and both are identical

Comment: @frz3993 You were right about the path, this seemed to be the issue. I do not understand why though as the php.ini files are the same related to paths... Please mark this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many differences in environment when you run the script through web browser compared to the cli.

When you use relative path in your script and run the script through cli, php will consider the file you are searching is relative to your current working directory. For example, if your current working directory is

```
/home/
```

and your script and file resides in the scripts directory

```
/var/www/html/script.php
/var/www/html/list.csv
```

When you run

```
php -f /var/www/html/script.php
```

or

```
php -f ..var/www/html/script.php
```

PHP will be searching the file relative to your working directory as

```
/home/list.csv
```

which doesn't exist. I first encountered such issue when I was trying to run PHP scripts from crontab which caused all relative path to break. So, it is either you change your working directory to `/var/www/html/` or just use absolute path, in your case

```
$file = fopen('/var/www/html/list.csv', 'r');
```